# How can I determine touch screen device in a bash script?

Tags: linux, touch, calibration

I am trying out the eGalax touch screen driver for my touch screen, as an alternative to the evdev/xinput_calibrator combination.

The calibration tool that comes with the eGalax driver, TKCal, takes the device to which the touch screen is connected as a command line argument.

Now I would like to start the calibration tool from a bash script. Is there some smart way to determine the device within the script, instead of hard coding "/dev/hidraw0" as in this example:

TKCal /dev/hidraw0 Cal

I presume that I can't rely on the touch screen landing on hidraw0 every time, can I? If I run my software on a different system, with a mouse and a keyboard and touch screen, I guess I have to handle that the devices can be conneted to different hdrawX devices. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Thank you very much!
/Fredrik Israelsson

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try looking at `/sys/class/hidraw/hidraw*/device/uevent`.

Answer (score 0):

The guys developing the eGalax drive told be to try a much simpler solution:
Write a udev rule that will map the touch screen to a device name of my choice.